# Ways to find the orthogonal projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

I'm a bit lost trying to find the projection matrix for an orthogonal projection onto a plane defined by the normal vector $n = (1, 1, 1)^T$. Then I can find the basis C of the plain $C = ( (-1,0,1)^T (0,-1,1)^T)$.

Now i should be able to find the projection Matrix with $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$
Where $A:=\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0\\
0 & -1\\
1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Then my the projection matrix will look like this?
$A:=\begin{bmatrix}
2/3 & -1/3 & -1/3\\
-1/3 & 2/3 & -1/3\\
-1/3 & -1/3 & 2/3\end{bmatrix}$ Is this correct?

To which basis is this projection matrix? How can I change the matrix to a different basis?

There should be another way to find the matrix. Something like add to my basis $C$ a vector from my basis $B$ (which should not be the standard basis) in $\mathbb{R^3}$, find the projection of the basis ( I only need to do this for the added basis vector from $B$ since the rest is already on the plane).

But how can I find the projection of the added basis vector?

After that what would be the matrix from basis B to B? The coefficients of the linear combinations $c_1,c_2,P(b_i)$ in B?

Comment: Is clear to you the way to obtain the projection matrix?

Comment: Not quite, I did it for a couple linear projections from R3 to R3. My approach was to find the basis of my vector space, project it, then the coefficients of the linear combination to my basis are the matrix.

Comment: I've added some explanation in the answer to explain the method.

Comment: If something is not clear free feel to ask me every explanation.

Comment: yes, thanks. I'll try to understand this, give me a couple of minutes more. I will comment your answer is i don't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily check for A considering the **product by the basis vector** of the plane, since $\forall v$ in the plane must be:

$$Av=v$$

Whereas for the normal vector:

$$An=0$$

Note that with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}:{c_1,c_2,n}$ the projection matrix is simply:

$$P_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

If you need the projection matrix with respect to another basis you simply have to apply a change of basis to obtain the new matrix.

For example with respect to the canonical basis, lets consider the matrix M which have vectors of the basis $\mathcal{B}:{c_1,c_2,n}$ as colums:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

If w is a vector in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ its expression in the canonical basis is $v$ give by:

$$v=Mw\implies w=M^{-1}v$$

Thus if the projection $w_p$ of w in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is given by:

$$w_p=P_{\mathcal{B}}w$$

The projection in the canonical basis is given by:

$$M^{-1}v_p=P_{\mathcal{B}}M^{-1}v\implies v_p=MP_{\mathcal{B}}M^{-1}v $$

Thus the matrix:

$$A=MP_{\mathcal{B}}M^{-1}=$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & \frac13 & \frac13\\
\frac13 & -1 & \frac13\\
\frac13 & \frac13 & \frac13\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2/3 & -1/3 & -1/3\\
-1/3 & 2/3 & -1/3\\
-1/3 & -1/3 & 2/3\end{bmatrix}$$

represent the **projection matrix in the plane with respect to the canonical basis**.

Suppose now we want find the **projection matrix from the base $\mathcal{B}$ to the canonical $\mathcal{C}$**.

Let's consider the projection $w_p$ of w in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is given by:

$$w_p=P_{\mathcal{B}}w$$

thus:

$$M^{-1}v_p=P_{\mathcal{B}}w\implies v_p=MP_{\mathcal{B}}w$$

Thus the matrix:

$$C=MP_{\mathcal{B}}=$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

represent the **projection matrix from the base $\mathcal{B}$ to the canonical $\mathcal{C}$**.

Comment: I don't get how we can construct the matrix $P_B$. Also when I try to calculate $P_Bn$ the outcome is $(1,1,0)^T$, then  $P(n) = 1* (-1,0,1)^T + 1* (0.-1,0)^t + 0$? Changing the basis seems clear now.

Comment: $P_B$ works on the basis B , you plug in a vector in the basis B and obtain the projection in the same basis. EG in the basis B $c_1$ is (1,0,0), $c_2$ is (0,1,0) and $n$ is (0,0,1).

Comment: I'm confused by the last column of $P_B$ with all zeros. According to your comment that column should be $(0,0,1)^T$? Or does that mean that if $P_Bn = (1,1,0)$ then its really the vector $(1,1,0)$ and i have to combine in B

Comment: With respect to the basis B the projection is trivial. Note that $P_Bc_1=c_1$, $P_Bc_2=c_2$, $P_Bn=0$. In this way every vector is projected in the plane. Once you have the trivial $P_B$ with the change of basis you can find the projection matrix A with respect to the canonical.

Comment: Why do we know that $P_Bn$ has to be 0?

Comment: By definition of projection matrix with respect to the plane, $n$ is the normal vector to the plane thus we want that $P_Bn=0$. And the same properties is true also for An=0.

Comment: When i compute An I indeed get (0,0,0) but with $P_B$ it's (1,1,0), why is this happening?

Comment: when you calculate with $P_B$ you are using basis $B$ thus $n$ is (0,0,1) and $P_B(0,0,1)=(0,0,0)$

Comment: ohh, yes, right. Thank you so much.

Comment: When I now find the transfer matrix from the basis $B = (c_1,c_2.n)$ to the normal basis C. What do I have to do? In my script: The transformation matrix from B to C $= P_C^{-1} * P_B$ (In my first post $A = P_C$) The matrix A can't be inverted. What else can I do?

Comment: Hi, have you found $A=MP_{\mathcal{B}}M^{-1}$?

Comment: @JDizzle I'm going to add some detail in the answer.

Comment: @JDizzle I've added the full calculation of Athat coincides with yours.

Comment: seems like i had some error while inverting, I'll try again and come back. Thanks

Comment: Found my error while inverting M, but still I can't invert A because the determinant is zero. Is there a different method to find the transformation matrix from B to the normal basis?

Comment: And in $A^{-1}$ the should be $-2/3$ instead of the -1's

Comment: of course A is singula since P is singular, projection matrix are always singular, why you need to consider $A^{-1}$?

Comment: Well I want to find a matrix which gets the coordinates of a vector to the basis B and outputs the projected vector coordinates to the standard basis. I don't know how this is called in English.

Comment: Ah ok! now I update the answer for this case also. It's simple by the method used also for A!

Comment: Oh, its just the same thing backwards. Thanks! Sadly I can't give more points.

Comment: You can also find form the canonical to B, can you see how do it?

Comment: $M^{-1}A$ should be right

Comment: Yes exactly that is $A=P_{\mathcal{B}}M^{-1}$, nice you got it!