# Find the vectors that span the space orthogonal to a given vector

Tags: orthogonality, gram-schmidt

I want to find the two vectors $v$ and $w$ that span a space orthogonal onto a given vector $A$$(A_x, A_y, A_z)$.

I suppose that the dot-product of *v* and *w* should be zero. As well as the dot-products of $v$ and $A$ and the dot-product of $w$ and $A$.

Afterwards I want to project a given vector $b$ onto the plane.

Comment: Since you've tagged the question with [tag:gram-schmidt], you seem to already know what you must do. What's stopping you? Why have you come here to ask a question instead of just doing it?

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The subspace orthogonal to $A(A_x, A_y, A_z)$ is the plane:

$$xA_x+y A_y+zA_z=0$$

thus is sufficient tha you pick two linearly independent vectors in the plane.

For the projection process take a look here [Ways to find the orthogonal projection matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570419/ways-to-find-the-orthogonal-projection-matrix/2570432#2570432).

Comment: @Arthur Yes but I have also added that it "is sufficient that you pick two linearly independent vectors in the plane" thus the  dot-product of v and w do not need to be zero. With this information there are all the elements to solve the OP. I'm waiting for request on others detail if necessary.