# projection a point into a subspace whose does not have orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I know how we can find the projection of a point into a subspace with orthogonal basis.

But suppose I have a 2 dimension subspace with basis:
$$V=\langle(1,2,3),(1,-3,-2)\rangle$$
obviously they are not orthogonal. Now I want to find the length of projection of $p=(4,1,2)$ to this subspace. How I can find it without finding orthogonal basis with Gram-Schmidt algorithm.

Is there any formula?

Comment: We need to construct the projection matrix.

Comment: @gimusi how I can find it?

Comment: I've given some short but sufficient hint, take also this related example here with full solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570419/ways-to-find-the-orthogonal-projection-matrix/2570432#2570432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

- consider a basis with vectors $v_1,v_2 \in V$ and $v_3$ orthogonal to them
- write down the projection matrix in this basis (it is trivial)

$$P_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

- change to the standard basis to find the projection matrix $A$

$$A=MP_{\mathcal{B}}M^{-1}$$

with $$M=[v_1 \quad v_2 \quad v_3]$$

Notably we have

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & -3 & 1\\
3 & -2 & -1\end{bmatrix}\qquad M^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac13 & -\frac1{15} & \frac4{15}\\
\frac13 & -\frac4{15} & \frac1{15}\\
\frac13 & \frac13 & -\frac13\end{bmatrix}$$

and then

$$A=MP_{\mathcal{B}}M^{-1}= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}\frac23&-\frac13&\frac13\\-\frac13&\frac23&\frac13\\\frac13&\frac13&\frac23\end{array}\right]$$

and finally $Ap=(3,0,3)\implies |Ap|=3\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I couldnt understand how you found this matrix? v3 is optional? is there any link that I can read it?

Comment: @shere it suffice that v_3 is orthogonal to $v_1$ and $v_2$ you can find it by inspection or by cross product, for example $v_3=(1,1,-1)$ is good.

Comment: @shere I've given a link with a full solution for a related problem

Comment: where is the link?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2570432/505767

Comment: how about if I have 2 vector in $R^{5}$? should I add 3 vectore which are orthogonal to those 2 vector?

Comment: We always need a basis thus three other vectors orthogonal to the given subspace but not necessarily  each other

Comment: when I use Gram–Schmidt process I get very different answer! why?

Comment: @shere If you show your work I can take a look to it.

Comment: @shere meanwhile I've added the full derivation for the projection matrix

Comment: I found my error, thanks

Comment: @shere well done! Bye

Answer (score 1):

With a small abuse of notation, form the matrix $V$ that has the elements of the basis as its columns. The order in which they appear is unimportant. Then the matrix $$P=V(V^TV)^{-1}V^T$$ is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto this subspace. You should be able to verify for yourself that $P^2=P$, so that this is indeed a projection, that it’s the identity map on the subspace $V$ (hint: compute $PV$) and that its null space is the orthogonal complement of the subspace $V$.

In this case, $$V = \left[\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\2&-3\\3&-2\end{array}\right]$$ and so $$P = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}\frac23&-\frac13&\frac13\\-\frac13&\frac23&\frac13\\\frac13&\frac13&\frac23\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: but when I use Gram–Schmidt process I get very different answer! which one is wrong?

Comment: @amd that's also a very effective way, maybe it should be usefull also to recall how it is derived ($Vx=q,q+e=p,e=p-q=p-Vx,e\perp q\implies V^TVx=V^Tp,...)$. What do you think about the other approch I've given? I prefer it often since with the same idea we can solve also different problems and not only projections.

Comment: I liked that, thanks

Comment: @shere for the derivation of this approach take a look here https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projections-onto-subspaces/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.2sum.pdf

Comment: @shere I get the same matrix by orthogonalizing the basis and then summing the individual projections. This result also agrees with gimusi’s, so the likeliest answer is that you’re making some mistake in your computation. Since you haven’t shown any of your work, it’s impossible to say what that might be.

Comment: @gimusi Both approaches are useful. I use yours when I have a known image and kernel (e.g., “project parallel to $V$”); the projection formula in my answer generalizes in a fairly simple way to arbitrary inner products. There are several ways to derive the formula. It turns up naturally when solving network flow problems, for instance. I like to think of it as the “bulk” version of the single-vector projection matrix $vv^T/v^Tv$.

Comment: @amd Thanks a lot, indeed  saw that kind of projection in the least square solution. Bye

Comment: @amd yes you are right