# How to find Projection matrix onto the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

I need help finding the projection of a matrix onto the subspace $W \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ given by the equation $x+y+z=0$

I am not sure what to start with to answer this question. Do I use projection formula?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HINT**

**1) Method 1**

- consider two linearly independent vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ $\in$ plane
- consider the matrix $A=[v_1\quad v_2]$
- the [projection matrix](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/198bde3a6536b62989b6cc09495575c1_MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.3sum.pdf) is $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

**2) Method 2 - more instructive**

[Ways to find the orthogonal projection matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570419/ways-to-find-the-orthogonal-projection-matrix/2570432#2570432)

Comment: Link to lecture notes is broken. Any chance you have a fix for it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes of course I’ll fix that asap or include a full explanation here! Thanks

Comment: @MadPhysicist I’ve restored the link.

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm looking for a citation for method 1 bullet 3, and MIT lecture notes are sufficient for my purposes, as is the textbook they are based on, unless you have a more authoritative source

Comment: @MadPhysicist Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang is a good source for introduction to the subject.

Comment: Most of the meat of my paper comes from that already. I used it in my undergraduate studies, and it generally fulfills all of my basic needs to this day.

Answer (score 2):

Write the defining equation of $W$ in matrix form $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = 0,$$ from which you should see that $W$ is the null space of the matrix on the left, that is, the orthogonal complement of the span of $(1,1,1)^T$. The orthogonal projection of a vector $v$ onto $W$ is then whatever’s left over after subtracting its projection onto $(1,1,1)^T$—i.e., the *orthogonal rejection* of $v$ from $(1,1,1)^T$. Therefore, the matrix of orthogonal projection onto $W$ is $I_3-P$, where $P$ is the matrix for projection onto $(1,1,1)^T$, which I’m assuming that you can compute using the projection formula that you mentioned.